# Why not combine the "for" and "while" loop to a single loop?

Tags: loops, programming-languages, language-design

I'm currently making my own programming language for fun using Ruby and wondering why having a "while" and "for" loop is something so universal. Why is it be bad to just have a single "loop" keyword?

ex)

```
loop (True) # acts as a while loop with a condition

loop var in 1..20 # acts as a for loop

loop var in list # acts as a for each loop
```

Would this somehow be disadvantageous or is the "while" and "for" loop simply just for semantic and readability?

Comment: That's not bad at all! Anyway, you should migrate this question to Programmer.SE

Comment: In general, the for loop is used when you have a known number of repetitions (12 months, 7 days, etc.). The while loop is used when a certain condition is met, and the number of times the loop will run is known or unknown, but usually unknown (run until a certain time is reached, etc.). The while loop is more versatile, but requires more attention from the programmer to avoid infinite loops.

Comment: Less is not more. "Real Perl programmers prefer things to be visually distinct." Larry Wall

Answer (score 2):

In fact, there are even more loop-variants. For example do-while.

To answer your question:
Yes, all of them can be used to do the same thing. However, depending on the loop-variant you use, you implicitly say what this loop does.

For example, you only use a for-loop if you know how often you want to loop (e.g. for each item in a list (i know, there is also a foreach in many languages)). It is considered bad habit to modify the loop variable inside a for-loop.

So if you are not sure how often you will loop, you should most likely use something else than a for-loop... for example a while-loop.

Here are some simple code examples:

```
for(i = 0; i < someList.Length; i++) {
  // do some stuff x times
}

while(someValue < someOtherValue) {
  someValue = someValue * someValue;
}
```

For me it is clear, that i should not use a for-loop for the 2nd loop.

To sum up: Yes, you only need one loop construct. However, I personally (!) like to have the advantage to actually say something just by the choice which loop i take.

Answer (score 2):

> Would this somehow be disadvantageous or is the "while" and "for" loop simply just for semantic and readability?

I think that your idea would not be disadvantageous and, yes, `while` and `for` are chosen for semantics/readability (or even historical reasons). Then, there are slightly different meanings in every language. Often, the `for` loop implies that you have a control variable. From the classic basic

```
for i=1 to 10 ... (next i)
```

to pascal, and even in more advanced constructs (iterators) from python, this idea is respected. Moreover, in some languages (pascal, for example) a `for` implies that the low-high limits are pre-calculated. This pascal code for example:

```
B := 5;
for i := 1 to B do begin
  B := 25
end;
```

can give warnings or errors, or can lead to 5 iterations even if in the body of the loop the upper limit is modified. The `C` language, which also has `for`, is totally different, even if the general idea of "control variable" is respected in 99% of the cases. The C `for` does not pre-compute limits (by design), can have more than one control variable, or even none at all:

```
for ( ; ; ) ...
```

is a valid `for` loop which does not have a control variable (and no meaning to break the loop!).

On the other hand, `while`, `repeat`, `do ... while` and so on are semantically clear (you can "talk" the code with your voice, and everything is self explaining), and do not imply variables (they imply nothing).

The above loops all have a common problem: they have a test which is performed at the beginning (or the end) of every iteration. Suppose you want to read characters from standard input, do something with them, and stop when this character is EOF. The C way is:

```
while ( ( ch=getchar() ) != EOF) ... ; // do something with ch
```

The C language can do this because an assignment is also an expression. If it was not so, one had to write:

```
ch=getchar();
while (ch != EOF) {
  .... ; // do something with ch
  ch = getchar();
}
// I must use two times the statement "ch = getchar();"

// or...

do {
  ch = getchar();
  if (ch == EOF) break;
  ... ; // do something with ch
} while (true)
// I use getchar() only once, but I end up with an awful "while (true)"
```

In your new language, you could invent a different cycle which goes like this:

```
cycle
  // statements always executed at least once
when (condition)
  // statement executed if the condition is true
  // and, if true, the cycle restarts
end
```

With this syntax, the example about getchar() would become:

```
cycle ch=getchar(); when (ch != EOF) ... ; // do something bla bla bla...
```

The normal `while`, `while (true)` and `do-while` loops would become:

```
cycle when (condition);  BODY  // while
cycle BODY;                    // while (true)
cycle BODY; when (condition)   // do-while
```

Think about it... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Most languages have `for` and `while` for historical reasons and familiarity. Familiarity is important: if you reuse the same concepts and keywords as other languages, your language is easier to learn. Many languages use "!" for the negation for this reason (many other languages use "not"). Look at this page comparing syntax across languages, you'll see lots of similarities: http://rigaux.org/language-study/syntax-across-languages.html

Now, to answer your question. Although most languages have the `while` keyword, you really don't need it.

Best example I can think of is Go:

```
// C-like for
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    sum += i
}

// while
for sum < 1000 {
    sum += sum
}

// infinite loop
for {
}

// do .. while
for ok := true; ok; ok = condition {
  ...
}

// range-for
for i, v := range pow {
    fmt.Printf("2**%d = %d\n", i, v)
}
```

So, as you can see, it's perfectly possible to use a single keyword for all loops.

Main reason for having both `for` and `while` is familiarity and readability. But you can easily do without.